# google drive java in the cloud

Tags: java, tomcat, google-drive-api

I followed this tutorial on how to connect to google drive. I took some liberty with using maven instead of gradle and a few details, but it worked. I inserted the relevant code into war file and deployed it in my localhost and it worked on the server. However, when I deployed the same war into google compute engine, it didn't work. Obviously it is because of this line.

```
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

I guess it invokes the authorization procedure on the machine of the tomcat, not user. I would expect there to be a way to deploy such a solution on web server, but I did not find it.

I think about moving my authorization to JS, and pass the token to backend, but that does not seem a good practise for me.

Regards

Comment: I suggest to try this [Java quickstart from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java). It has a step wherein you need to set-up your credentials for your app to access the drive. After you have completed the quickstart, you can now make requests to the Drive API.

Comment: Yea, that was the exact tutorial I was following, and I got stuck on the issue explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I kept digging in the Internet for a while and found class
[com.google.api.client.extensions.servlet.auth.oauth2.AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/extensions/servlet/auth/oauth2/AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet) (and AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet from the same package).

Weird it was nowhere in the google tutorials. It is quite close to what I need, so I keep working on it.
For everyone interested in the matter:
It seems that google authorizations don't like external IP addresses, so I need to set up domain properly, but that is another story.